# how to set minimum order amount in shopify without wholesale?

Tags: shopify, shopify-liquid

how to set minimum order amount for all products (pickup & delivery) in shopify without wholesale app?

how to set minimum order amount in shopify without wholesale? I want to add set a minimum price for all products. when customer click on  cart the must be 200$ or maximum.